# Rails Date.today to MMDD format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I transform Date.today object to return the date in format `MMDD`?
For instance, for today, this should be:

```
0304
```

Comment: Does my solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method:

```
Date.today.strftime('%d%m')
# => "0304"
```